# IE9 Checkbox rendering oddity on focus

Tags: css, internet-explorer, checkbox

[image: Checkboxes]

Check the screenshot. You'll notice that the  checkbox that has focus is actually rendering differently from the other checkboxes.  What would make it appear this way in IE9?

I've got the following CSS snippet, and I've noticed only that if I remove ALL of the following CSS this issue no longer happens. But if I just remove any one or two of these rules it will still happen.  I'm baffled.

```
textarea:active,
textarea:focus,
textarea:active:hover,
textarea:focus:hover,
select:active,
select:focus,
select:active:hover,
select:focus:hover,
input:active,
input:focus,
input:active:hover,
input:focus:hover{
    background-color:#f9f9f5;
    border-color:#658cae;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 8px #7899b5;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 8px #7899b5;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 8px #7899b5;

    z-index:1;/* for Opera */
}
input[type="file"]:focus,
input[type="file"]:active,
input[type="radio"]:focus,
input[type="radio"]:active,
input[type="checkbox"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:active {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
input[type="file"]:focus,
input[type="file"]:active,
input[type="file"][disabled],
input[type="radio"]:focus,
input[type="radio"]:active,
input[type="radio"][disabled],
input[type="checkbox"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:active,
input[type="checkbox"][disabled]{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Here's a live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QRzRw/1/

Comment: It's also worth noting that this does NOT happen to radio buttons, which are similar and have the exact same CSS rules applied to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the evil part:

```
input:focus,
input:active:hover,
input:focus:hover{
  background-color:#f9f9f5;
  border-color:#658cae;
}
```

It seems, once you made this setting, it can't be undone by assigning `transparent` or `inherit`.

Looks like you have to add these styles for all `input[type=...]` tags, except those for type checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer, by default, uses Windows form controls for HTML forms.  These are standard, styled exactly like they would be in any Windows application... until you try and apply styles to them manually.

This can be demonstrated with an ordinary text input.  If you try and set the `background-color` property, the overall style of the input element will change along with it, because Internet Explorer switches from the standard Windows form control to a custom form control.  For your convenience, I've set up that demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AEjhe/).

Other versions of Internet Explorer behave the same way.  A possible workaround would be to target the CSS toward non-IE browsers only, using a method like [Paul Irish's conditional CSS classes](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Answer (score 2):

A friend helped me out with this and he figured out that setting a border or background color on a checkbox will cause it to render like that for some odd reason.

NGLN is correct and I'll accept his answer.  I had to change my CSS to the following for this to work:

```
textarea,
select,
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="text"]{
    font-family:'ColaborateRegular';
    background-color:#efefeb;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#89969f #89969f #cbcbc8 #89969f;
    outline: 0;
    padding:3px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;

    -webkit-appearance: none;

    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s, border-color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s, border-color 0.4s;
    -ms-transition:background-color 0.4s, border-color 0.4s;
    -o-transition:background-color 0.4s, border-color 0.4s;
    transition:background-color 0.4s, border-color 0.4s;
}
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
}
textarea:hover,
select:hover,
input[type="email"]:hover,
input[type="number"]:hover,
input[type="password"]:hover,
input[type="search"]:hover,
input[type="tel"]:hover,
input[type="text"]:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 5px #7899b5;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 5px #7899b5;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 5px #7899b5;
}
textarea:active,
textarea:focus,
textarea:active:hover,
textarea:focus:hover,
select:active,
select:focus,
select:active:hover,
select:focus:hover,
input[type="email"]:active,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:active:hover,
input[type="email"]:focus:hover,
input[type="number"]:active,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:active:hover,
input[type="number"]:focus:hover,
input[type="password"]:active,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:active:hover,
input[type="password"]:focus:hover,
input[type="search"]:active,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:active:hover,
input[type="search"]:focus:hover,
input[type="tel"]:active,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:active:hover,
input[type="tel"]:focus:hover,
input[type="text"]:active,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:active:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus:hover{
    background-color:#f9f9f5;
    border-color:#658cae;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 8px #7899b5;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 8px #7899b5;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #b8b7b3, 0 0 8px #7899b5;

    z-index:1;/* for Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but I believe I have a better solution. I seem to get the same in IE 8 + 9

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
input[type="checkbox"] {
     outline:0;border:0;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```